# Hosting control panel with Java EE Application Server support?

Tags: jakarta-ee, hosting, controlpanel

I currently have WHM/cPanel on my server, but it doesn't integrate properly with any Java EE App Server. I installed Tomcat manually, and have made it work through Apache, but the configuration is more fragile than I'd like.

So, I'm trying to find a replacement where a Java EE App Server can be properly integrated & managed.

Requirements:

- Open Source / Free Software (i.e. not proprietary)
- Runs on CentOS (although, Debian/Fedora Core/FreeBSD are options if necessary)
- Supports Apache + Tomcat (or equivalent)
- Self-monitoring (e.g. auto-restarts MySQL if it falls over)
- User account management (easy setup, limit space & bandwidth quotas, etc)
- Friendly end-user control panel (for configuring db, mail, stats, logs, etc)
- Anything obvious I've forgotten.

Are there any recommended software packages which do all of this?

Comment: http://faq.cpanel.net/show.cgi?qa=120310982800498

Comment: http://www.apluskb.com/scripts/How_do_I_manage_my_answer2108.html

Comment: cPanel *claims* to support Tomcat, but it doesn't actually work properly. (Although I've not actually tested with the latest cPanel releases).

Plesk is not supported by my provider, so I would need to purchase it myself, and it is ridiculously expensive.

Comment: I recently found OpenPanel and it looked potentially interesting, but I've not yet had a chance to investigate it further.

Comment: [Kloxo](http://lxcenter.org/software/kloxo) is another interesting and Open Source (AGPL3) one that I need to investigate further - doesn't directly support Tomcat, but still plays nice with it.

Answer (score 1):

[Plesk](http://www.parallels.com/products/plesk/) is a similar commercial hosting management suite similar to CPanel, in fact most hosting providers who offer WHM/CPanel also offer Plesk, which has built in Tomcat support.  Plesk runs natively on CentOS but it is only free for use on one domain.

Comment: That last bit is the problem - needs to support *lots* of domains!

Answer (score 0):

We have been using [Apache Geronimo](http://geronimo.apache.org/) here at work for about two years and it has been rock solid. It has its own built-in control panel that allows us to deploy/start/stop each app separately. You may want to give it a try.

Comment: I couldn't see anything about user account management and monitoring other services (e.g. MySQL) - is this done with a GBean or some other method?